# Infinitely many squares of form 50^m - 50^n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I wanted to solve this problem. You have to prove that there are infinitely many square numbers of the form  $(50^m - 50^n)$ (and no square numbers of the form $(2020^m + 2020^n)$ with $m$ and $n$ being positive whole numbers.

I tried many approaches but just couldn‘t manage to do it.
For example: if you factor out $50^n$ you get $50^n(50^{(m-n)}-1)$ and that means, that if $a = m-n$, then $50^a - 1$ is a square as well, but I couldn't prove that either.

I just need an approach to see how I could go about solving such a problem. 
Thanks

Comment: The problem in the title and in the body are different. Also, include the approaches you tried.

Comment: Sorry, the expression in the title was wrong.

Comment: Hint: Note that $50-1$ is a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$50^{2k+1}-50^{2k}=(7\cdot 50^k)^2$$

Comment: To complete this answer, show that $2020^m+2020^n$ can't be a square since it's congruent to $2\bmod3$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I kinda feel stupid now.